# Get SelectOneMenu 's selected item from code

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get a primefaces SelectOneMenu selected item's name from code:

This is my SelectOneMenu:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formMain:somSelect");
```

The Component is found.
I already tried to cast it into a SelectOneMenu but I won't get a method like "getSelectedValue()" which is written in the user manual in "client side api".
I also tried:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formMain:somSelect").getAttributes().get("label");
```

But this returns NPE.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="somSelect" value="#{userManagerBean.somValue}" valueChangeListener="#{userManagerBean.somListener}" styleClass="selecters">
<f:selectItems value="#{userSelectBean.userList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

UserManagerBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserManagerBean {

    private String somValue;
    private String selectedUser;
    private List<User> userData;    
    private List<User> users;

    public UserManagerBean() {  

    }

    public String getSomValue(){
        return somValue;        
    }

    public void setSomValue(String somValue){
        this.somValue = somValue;
    }

    // Getter for Table Content
    public List<User> getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }
```

Any ideas?

**€: The problem is that the selected item is only returned in the getter if I call a method and an ajax update:**

```
<p:ajax update="panelMain" listener="#{userManagerBean.changeEvent}" />
```

But I don't get an correct selected item on page load ( item = null ).

Comment: Why are you complicating with this? You probably bound value of component to backing bean property?

Comment: I also tried that but I didn't get the selected items name as a value and also my valueChangeListener doesn't work: doesn't get called if I change selected item. To be more precise: the getter returns null for **somValue**

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your backing bean? Class definition, annotations, and getter and setter for this property `somValue`.

Comment: Added relevant content of backing bean.

Comment: Of course you're getting a null on page load. `somValue` is null on page load. Or are you initializing it somewhere?

Comment: Thanks my mistake, you are right kolossus! You can write it as an answer so I can accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using list of beans to populate `f:selectItems` you should add converter or provide `itemValue` attribute. In your case as value is `String` provide `itemValue` with some `String` identifier of your `User` bean:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{userSelectBean.userList}" var="u" itemValue="#{u.code}" itemLabel="#{u.name}"/>
```

Change properties `code` and `name` to those which you have in your `User` bean. Be shore that `itemValue` points to `String` as your value in backing bean is `String`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know what the problem is. The getter returns always null for **somValue** when I load the page. Only when I call the bean again (from a button e.g.) the correct value is returned. Any idea on a workaround would be much appreciated!